# How do I check if Vim is currently recording a macro?

Tags: vimscript, macro

Is there a way to programmatically check if Vim is currently in the recording mode triggered by <kbd>q</kbd>?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Vim 8.1-0020, there is a [`reg_recording()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#reg_recording%28%29) function that'll return the name of the current register being recorded. An empty string is returned if we are not recording.

Comment: That is the correct answer.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt. Well, it depends if the script needs to target older versions of Vim. In that case, statox' solution may be the only workaround available.

Comment: Why is vim using underscore notations for new functions? Isn't underscore notation deprecated in vim (I noticed a lot like `buffer_name()` is replaced by `bufname()`)?

Comment: @wengwengweng you should ask such questions on vim-dev mailing list

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** I wasn't aware of `reg_recording()` but if you have a newer version of Vim Luc's answer is clearly the best answer.

I'm not aware of a built-in way to check if Vim is recording but you could use the following workaround in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:isRecording = get(g:, 'isRecording', 0)
nnoremap q :let g:isRecording = !g:isRecording<CR>q
```

The first line will create a global variable `g:isRecording` which is falsy by default or takes its existing value if you re-source your `.vimrc`.

Then you remap <kbd>q</kbd> to toggle the value of `g:isRecording` when it toggles the recording mode and you can then test `g:isRecording`.

That's not the most elegant solution but as [`:h recording`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording) doesn't seem to mention a variable which would change with <kbd>q</kbd> and [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) doesn't mention an event related to recording, I guess that the easiest way to do.

Comment: I'm curious. Why have you preferred to define an autocommand to initialize the global variable instead of setting it in the vimrc? (with `let g:isRecording = get(g:, 'isRecording', 0)` to permit to source the vimrc as many times as we wish)

Comment: @LucHermitte It was because I didn't think of resourcing the vimrc :)